Google Ads Tag Not Receiving User ID from GTM Data Layer
I'm currently working on passing the User ID to Google Ads using Google Tag Manager (GTM). I've successfully configured the data layer to pass the User ID, and I can see this working correctly in GTM's preview mode, as shown in the screenshot below:
https://imgur.com/7lEkFcO
However, the User ID does not appear to be pushed into Google Ads. I've followed the steps to configure the Google Ads tag to capture the User ID, but it seems like something is missing or incorrectly set.
Here are the steps I've taken so far:

Configured the data layer to include the User ID.
Verified in GTM preview mode that the User ID is being passed correctly.
Set up the Google Ads tag to include the User ID variable. https://imgur.com/FU4kjxb
I have setup google tag to pass user_id into google Analytics:  https://imgur.com/uk3lnW4
I have checked in the debug mode in google analyrics to see if i can find the User ID. But i cant.
List item

Despite these steps, the User ID is not showing up in Google Ads.
What could be the possible reasons for this issue?

Could there be an issue in when i am triggering the tags?
Are there any specific debugging steps i can follow?

Feel free to modify the question to better suit your specific situation or any additional details you might want to include.
